# Reduce symbolic expressions with MatrixSymbol (reduce +- to -)

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I am using SymPy to write mathematical proofs which are automatically included in a Latex document. Unfortunately in some cases sympy returns equations with a '+-' instead of - and adds an additional 1 in front of some symbolic variables.

Minimal Example: (*tested on Python 3.6.0 and Sympy 1.1*)

```
from sympy import *
n = Symbol('n')
p = Symbol('p')
q = Symbol('q')
Ci = MatrixSymbol('Ci', q,n)
Li = MatrixSymbol('Li', p,n)
Sl = MatrixSymbol('Sl', p, n) 
Tl = MatrixSymbol('Tl', p, q) 
Xi31 = (Li-Tl*Ci-Sl)
Xi31
```

which returns

> −1Sl+−1TlCi+L

Question: How Do I get

> −Sl−TlCi+L

simplify() and block_collapse() do not have any effect.

Comment: Internally, subtraction A-B is always represented as addition `A + (-1)*B`. You can see the internal representation with `srepr(Xi31)`.  The issue here is with printing: the string (or latex) representation of expressions with MatrixSymbol is not as human-friendly as it should be. I opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/14237).